# c++ delete node linked list causing program to crash

Tags: c++, linked-list, crash

When I run my delete node function, it ends up crashing the command screen.. I know what lines of code are causing the crash. I think it is crashing because I'm trying to make a pointer point to an invalid node, but I may be wrong. Here is the full code of the delete function. It only seems to occur when it runs. These are the lines of code that are causing the crash:

```
void InventoryList::deleteNode(int num)
{
ListNode *previousNode; //To point to the previous node
ListNode *nodePtr; //to traverse the list


int number = 2;

//if the head is empty do nothing
if (!head)
{
    return;

}
//Determine if the first node is the value
if (1 == num)
{

    nodePtr = head->next;
    delete head;
    head = nodePtr;

}
else
{
    //intialize the node as head.
    nodePtr = head;


    //Skip nodes whose value is not equal to num.
    while (nodePtr != nullptr && number != num)
    {
        previousNode = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;

        number++;
    }
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        previousNode = nodePtr;
        previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
        delete nodePtr;

    }
}
```

### }

Source code

```
void viewInv(InventoryList& inv, Item& heroArmor, Item& heroWeapon, Hero&     hero)
{
int x = 0;
string y;
inv.displayList();
Item equip;

cout << "Do you wish to use/equip an item? If so please enter Yes, else enter No" << endl;

cin >> y;
if (y == "Yes" || y == "yes" || y == "YES")
{
    cout << "Please enter the position corrosponding to the item you wish to use." << endl;
    cin >> x;
//calling the function to retreive the item from the inventory
    equip = inv.returnNode(x);
    cout << equip;

//calling the delete function.
    inv.deleteNode(x);
    system("pause");

    if (equip.getType() == "Blunt" || equip.getType() == "Stab" || equip.getType() == "Slash")
    {
        inv.appendNode(heroWeapon);
        heroWeapon = equip;
    }
    else if (equip.getType() == "Light" || equip.getType() == "Medium" || equip.getType() == "Heavy")
    {
        inv.appendNode(heroArmor);
        heroArmor = equip;
    }
    else if (equip.getType() == " ")
    {
        cout << "There is no item." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        heal(hero);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You should check [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and on posting [MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code snippets are not enough for others to reproduce the problem because your issue might be elsewhere and just gets noticed when you try to delete.

Comment: @Hayden, why don't you post the full code? that will solve your problem more quickly

Comment: why does number = 2 here? is there a node->data that should be compared to the int num?

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay How much should I post? Should I just go and post the all the classes and source? I'd rather not have to do that, since its a few thousand lines of code. Or should I just keep this function posted, and post the source code portion of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: To @SnG that must have been an error, it should have been a 1. Now it doesn't crash at that point,. It equips the item as I wanted, but now when it ends to program it crashes instead

Comment: try deleting the line `previousNode = nodePtr;` in  `if (nodePtr)` . See if that works

Comment: @SnG Nope, does change it crashing at the end. Could it be a problem with my linked lists destructor? since it would use the destrcutor at the end of program, and that's where the crash seems to be occuring. The thing that confuses me, when I comment out these three lines of code:

previousNode = nodePtr;
   previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
   delete nodePtr;

I get no crash.

Comment: try commenting out only the delete to test your destructor. also please post what your error message is

Comment: @SnG I commented out just the delete nodePtr, and it worked fine. Also, I'm not getting an error message, its just stops and crashes, and I get a notification that says:

Debug Assertion Failed!

(flash drive location)

Expression _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the previous node to nodePtr, which probably will cause you to try to delete the stuff you already deleted the next time you run this line. Do a step by step using a debugger if you have one or post the full source code.

Comment: I tried deleted/commenting out the part where I set previous node to nodePtr, but it still crashed.